# Unable to remove wireless drivers from HP laptop

Tags: wifi, windows-10

We do have HP Laptops for the users where we dont need any wireless Adapters.

We tried uninstalling Wireless drivers from device manager, after a reboot the wireless adapter reappear again.

We restrict most of the websites from firewall. Users are trying to connect wireless to their mobile hotspot network. (All the users are Local Admins on their respective laptops)

How do we remove drivers Completely?

All the laptops (HP Pro Book 450 G1) are running on Windows10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to disable the wireless entirely, I'd suggest disabling the adapter in the BIOS, and configuring a BIOS setup password. This will prevent the wireless adapter from appearing in the OS at all.

Alternatively, you could physically remove the wireless adapters from the laptops.

Comment: I think Disabling adapter from BIOS will WORK :D , 
Where do i find this Wireless adapter in BIOS ? ill try this anyway :D

Comment: It depends specifically on your laptop model, but there should be a section regarding Networking or Integrated Devices that references the WLAN device.